# How to vertically align arrow icon to the center

Tags: button, icons, vertical-alignment

I would like to align an arrow icon (wrapped in an `<i>` tag) to align to the center of the button (vertically). It works when only one line of text is in the button, but as soon as the text gets to two lines, the alignment of the arrow is off. How do I fix this? Any help is much appreciated!

```css
.btn-container {
 margin: 2% 0;
 max-width:350px;
}

.btn-container a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:#5A469B;
 font-size:1.2em;
 text-align:left;
 line-height:1.2;
 padding-left:20px;
}

.btn-rectangle p {
 color:#fff;
 text-align:left;
}

.btn-rectangle {
 background-color:#fff;
 border: solid 3px #5A469B;
 padding:8% 5%;
    display:block;
 width:100%;
 text-transform:capitalize;
}

.btn-rectangle:hover {
 background-color:#5A469B;
 color:#fff;
 border:solid 3px #5A469B;
 -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
 -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
 -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
 -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
 transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.flaticon-move13 {
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-size:1.2em;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.move-right  {
 float:right;
}

@font-face {
 font-family: "Flaticon";
 src: url("flaticon.eot");
 src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
 url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"),
 url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"),
 url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before, [class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after, [class*=" flaticon-"]:after {   
 font-family: Flaticon;
font-style: normal;
}.flaticon-arrow395:before {
 content: "\e000";
}
.flaticon-bottom4:before {
 content: "\e001";
}
.flaticon-move13:before {
 content: "\e002";
}
```

```html
                <div class="btn-container">
                    <a href="#" class="btn-rectangle">the square represents the arrow. Once it's two lines of text it isn't aligned.
                    <i class="move-right flaticon-move13"></i></a>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below -- should work for you. A few things to note that might help.

If the max-width is important, set your box sizing
to include the margins, border etc add this.

```
*:after, *:before {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You don't need both:before and :after (only need to declare the font once)

If you use SCSS I'd use an pseudo class and @extends like I posted below. Keeps Your HTML Clean and helps avoids duplicate code.

Best of Luck Hope it works for you!

```css
.btn-container {
  margin: 2% 0;
  max-width: 350px;
}
.btn-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5A469B;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 1.2;
  /* padding-left: 20px; */
}
.btn-rectangle p {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
}
.btn-rectangle {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #5A469B;
  padding: 8% 5%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  width: 100%;
}
.btn-rectangle:hover {
  background-color: #5A469B;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #5A469B;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.flaticon-move13 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*/
 //
 //Goodbye Floats -- Flexbox FTW
 --------------------------------- */

/*.move-right  {*/

/*//float:right;*/

/*}*/

@font-face {
  font-family: "Flaticon";
  src: url("flaticon.eot");
  src: url("flaticon.eot#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("flaticon.woff") format("woff"), url("flaticon.ttf") format("truetype"), url("flaticon.svg") format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
[class^="flaticon-"]:before,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:before,
[class^="flaticon-"]:after,
[class*=" flaticon-"]:after {
  font-family: Flaticon;
  font-style: normal;
}
.flaticon-arrow395:before {
  content: "\e000";
}
.flaticon-bottom4:before {
  content: "\e001";
}
.flaticon-move13:before {
  content: "\e002";
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
    <a href="#" class="btn-rectangle">the square represents the arrow. Once it's two lines of text it isn't aligned.
        <i class="flaticon-move13"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
// SCSS Example
     %flaticons {
            font-family: 'Flaticon';
            font-style: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            word-wrap: normal;
            white-space: nowrap;
            direction: ltr;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            speak: none;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        }

         .icon-arrow {
          @extend %flaticons;

          &:after {
            content: "\e000";
          }
        }

             .icon-bottom {
          @extend %flaticons;

          &:after {
            content: "\e001";
          }
        }
    // ======================================================
    // Renders to
     .icon-arrow, .icon-bottom, .icon-movel {
          font-family: 'Flaticon';
            font-style: normal;
            letter-spacing: normal;
            word-wrap: normal;
            white-space: nowrap;
            direction: ltr;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            speak: none;
            text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
     }

    .icon-arrow:after { content: "\e000"; }
    .icon-bottom:after { content: "\e001"; }
    .icon-bottom:after { content: "\e002"; }
```